# Error when using test user in Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have setup a Facebook dev test-user for a Facebook app.  When i post to the wall as the test user, I get:

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

The strange thing, the post is successfull, and i cant duplicate this on a "real" account (like my personal account).  It only happens with the test user from what i can reproduce.  Another oddity, as you can see from the picture below, when looking at the Wall, it repeats my posts forever, yet if I do a Get("/me/feed"), it returns the correct number of posts and no repeats.  Is this just a case of the FB test-user being flakey?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chalked this up to flakey FB dev account.  This behavior never exibits itself on a real account.